# How to create moving animation when click other item in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm facing this challenge, client want me to make a moving animation when click other item in a top nav bar, it will have animation that switch to another item:
[image]
something like apple music, as video below:
https://streamable.com/yg1j2j

But i have no idea where to start with this, please help, thank you a lots

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve this using the following setup.

1. Create a top level container `View` that contains two children: A `FlatList` that holds our items ("Products", "Stores", ...) and an `Animated.View` which will represent our animated background color of the selected item.
2. Create a state that stores a `Animated.Value` which we will use to create a smooth movement of our `Animated.View` on item selection.

This solution is a little bit hacky since we explicitly use the knowledge that we have of the items in our list. There might be a better more general solution for this.

Here is a minimal working example and a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/animated-list-selection) where you can try out my solution.

```js
const data = [
    {
      id: "1",
      text: "Results",
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      text: "Products",
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      text: "Stores",
    },
  ]

  const [translateValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)

  const onPress = React.useCallback(
    (index) => {
      setSelected(index)
      Animated.spring(translateValue, {
        toValue: index * 100,
        velocity: 5,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start()
    },
    [translateValue, setSelected]
  )

return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 100 }}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          {
            position: "absolute",
            backgroundColor: "black",
            top: -5,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 15,
            width: 70,
            height: 30,
            borderRadius: 12,
            transform: [{ translateX: translateValue }],
          },
        ]}
      />
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        horizontal={true}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(index)}>
              <View style={{ width: 100, borderRadius: 10 }}>
                <Text style={[{ textAlign: "center" }, index === selected ? { color: "white" } : { color: "black" }]}>
                  {item.text}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  )
```

Comment: So detail, thank for your answer

Comment: Hi @David, i'm very appreciate your answer, i really want to learn more about animation, can you give me some good resource to start?

Comment: In my experience the best way to learn is to solve problems. There is no real difference in learning react native animations or in learning any other programming technique. Search a little project that you would like to implement and than just start. If you have troubles to proceed ask a question here. In general, the best resource is the official documentation of `react-native-animation`. That might be e bit demotivating at first but the best way is to just start!

Comment: Thank for answer David, but i have another question, so in above example, if i use flatlist, how can i make the position of the animated view stick on item, if i use scroll, the animated compnent stick on the view and look very weird

Comment: I made a little trick if you look closely. I set `scrollEnabled={false}` which disables scrolling, since I‘m working with absolute positions. If you want to use scrolling and the animation than this is not an easy problem to solve I‘m afraid..